# Undefined variables on session all of a sudden without making any changes

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

```
<?

session_start();

$client_name=$_SESSION['client_name'];

if ($client_name !== 'admin')
{
include "client_header.php";
$client_id=$_SESSION['client_id'];
$first_name=$_SESSION['first_name'];
$last_name=$_SESSION['last_name'];
$remoteaddr=$_SESSION['remoteaddr'];
$date_in=$_SESSION['date_in'];
$time_in=$_SESSION['time_in'];
$cisloggedin=$_SESSION['cisloggedin'];

$url_access=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ;

$isql = "INSERT INTO patient (first_name,last_name, email, country , address , phone , gender , height , weight , bloodpressure , bloodtype)
VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$country','$address','$phone','$gender','$height','$weight','$bloodpressure','$bloodtype')";
$result = mysql_query($isql);
?>
<h2><br>Welcome <b>
  <?=$client_name?>

  Here are your bills:
  </b></h2>

<?

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE clientid = '$client_id' ORDER BY id",$db);

echo "<p><table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 bordercolor=#000000 width=90%>";
echo "<tr align=top>
<td class=topHeadrow5><b>Inv. #</b></td>
<td class=topHeadrow5><b>Receipt Date</b></td>
<td class=topHeadrow5><b>Due Date</b></td>
<td class=topHeadrow5><b>Total</b></td>
<td class=topHeadrow5><b>Status</b></td>
<td class=topHeadrow5>&nbsp;</td></tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $row["id"];
    $date = $row["date"];
    $bill_date = $row["bill_date"];
    $due_date = $row["due_date"];
    $paid_date = $row["paid_date"];
    $dateshow = fixDate($date);
    $dateshow1 = fixDate($bill_date);
    $dateshow2 = fixDate($due_date);
    $dateshow3 = fixDate($paid_date);
    $total = $row["total"];
    $status = $row["status"];

if ($alternate == "1") {
    $color = "#ffffff";
    $alternate = "2";
    }
    else {
    $color = "#c0c0c0";
    $alternate = "1";
    }

echo "<tr valign=top bgcolor=$color><td>$id</td><td>$dateshow</td><td>$dateshow2</td><td align=right>$currency$total</td>";
if($status == "paid"){
echo "<td bgcolor=#33cc33>$status</td>";
}else{
echo "<td>$status</td>";
}
echo "<td>[ <a href='invoice.php?id=$id'>view</a> ] [ <a target=_blank href='invoice_print.php?id=$id'>Print</a> ]</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
//-------------------------------------------------Begin Admin-------------------------------------------------
}
elseif ($client_name == 'admin')
{
include "header.php";

$url_access=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ;

?>
<h2><br>Hello <b>
  <?=$client_name?>

  Patients List:
  </b></h2>

<?

if ($menusort1 = $menusort1) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT invoices.*, clients.*
FROM invoices,clients
WHERE invoices.clientid = clients.clientid && invoices.date >'$ytd'
ORDER BY $menusort1 ASC",$db);

}
if ($menusort = $menusort) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT invoices.*, clients.*
FROM invoices,clients
WHERE invoices.clientid = clients.clientid && invoices.date >'$ytd'
ORDER BY $menusort DESC",$db);

}
if (!$menusort and !$menusort1) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT invoices.*, patient.*
FROM invoices,patient
WHERE invoices.clientid = clients.clientid && invoices.date >'$ytd'
ORDER BY id",$db);
}
echo "<p><table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 bordercolor=#000000 width=95%>";
echo "<tr align=top>
<td class=topHeadrow5><b>ID number: <a href='menu.php?menusort=id'><img class=arrows src=images/dn_arrow.gif></a><a href='menu.php?menusort1=id'><img class=arrows src=images/up_arrow.gif></a></b></td>
<td class=topHeadrow5><b>Name <a href='menu.php?menusort=name'><img class=arrows src=images/dn_arrow.gif></a><a href='menu.php?menusort1=name'><img class=arrows src=images/up_arrow.gif></a></b></td>
<td class=topHeadrow5><b>Out Patient<a href='menu.php?menusort=date'><img class=arrows src=images/dn_arrow.gif></a><a href='menu.php?menusort1=date'><img class=arrows src=images/up_arrow.gif></a></b></td>
<td class=topHeadrow5><b>Due Date <a href='menu.php?menusort=due_date'><img class=arrows src=images/dn_arrow.gif></a><a href='menu.php?menusort1=due_date'><img class=arrows src=images/up_arrow.gif></a></b></td>
<td class=topHeadrow5>&nbsp;</td>
<td class=topHeadrow5>&nbsp;</td>
<td class=topHeadrow5>&nbsp;</td>
<td class=topHeadrow5>&nbsp;</td></tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $row["id"];
    $clientid = $row["clientid"];
    $name = $row["first_name"];
    $date = $row["date"];
    $bill_date = $row["bill_date"];
    $due_date = $row["due_date"];
    $paid_date = $row["paid_date"];
    $dateshow = fixDate($date);
    $dateshow1 = fixDate($bill_date);
    $dateshow2 = fixDate($due_date);
    $dateshow3 = fixDate($paid_date);




if ($alternate == "1") {
    $color = "#ffffff";
    $alternate = "2";
    }
    else {
    $color = "#e5e5e5";
    $alternate = "1";
    }

echo "<tr valign=top bgcolor=$color>
<td width=10>$id</td><td>$name</td>
<td>$dateshow</td><td>$dateshow2</td>
<td align=right>$currency$total</td>";
if ($status == 'pending') {
echo "<td  bgcolor=$color>$status</td>";

} else {
echo "<td class=rowviewinv >$status</td>";
}
if ($status == 'pending') {
echo "<td>[ <a href='admin_invoice.php?id=$id'>view / change status</a> ]</td>";
}
else {
echo "<td class=rowviewinv>[ <a class=inv_links href='admin_invoice.php?id=$id'>view</a> ]</td>";
}
if ($status == 'pending') {
echo "<td>[ <a href='notifyclient.php?id=$id&clientid=$clientid'>notify client</a> ]</td>";
} else {
echo "<td class=rowviewinv>[ Paid $dateshow3 ]</td>";
}

echo "<td>[ <a href='edit_invoice.php?id=$id'>edit</a> ]</td><td>[ <a href='delete_invoice.php?id=$id' onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure?')\">delete</a> ]</td></tr>";
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT sum(total) AS sum FROM invoices WHERE date >'.$ytd.'");
$sum = mysql_result($result,0,"sum");

if ($sum == 1){
echo "";
}else{
echo "";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
<p align="center"><font class="medBold">You can review previous dates by selecting from the calendar icons.
</font></p>
<form method="post" name=form1 action="invoice_history.php">
<input type="text" name="invdate" id="invdate">
<img src="img.gif" id="f_trigger_c"
     style="cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid red;"
     title="Date selector"
     onmouseover="this.style.background='red';"
     onmouseout="this.style.background=''" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    Calendar.setup({
        inputField     :    "invdate",
        ifFormat       :    "%Y-%m-%d",
        button         :    "f_trigger_c",
        align          :    "Tl",
        singleClick    :    true
    });
</script>
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit Invoice Date"></form>
<?
}

?>
```

it worked fine before. I didnt do anything since i wasnt the one who made the codes. what i only did was copy the file to a new folder but both files doesnt work. In the database, i did modify some but not in the database of the one that is being used by that program.

Comment: there is no `client_header.php` in the path. that's it.

Answer (score 3):

`include "client_header.php";`

You are missing this file, and as a result it's possibly throwing the rest of the code off. You probably moved these files to a differnt directory, change the `include` to allow for the directory change.

There are other `include` in the code, so update those also.

// Edit

Check the original source, as you say this is someone else's code, there may be a copy present.  The `include` command indicates that the `client_header.php` file will be available, either in the same folder or as part of the `PATH`.  See [Php include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) documentation and the [notes on include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) for more details.

The only other possibility is that these errors existed before but were not visible due to php settings.

Comment: I didnt delete any file. I even checked the ones uploaded online and there is no client_header.php

Comment: @user1551672 I have updated the answer, the file must exist somewhere as the code has explicit asked for it be added.

Comment: So the client_header.php is not a pre-made file cause i thought maybe it was.. I hope when my groupmate sees this he could fix it or something. Cause i tried searching for that file.. nothing. I even checked the one that was emailed to me last week. there is no client_header file.

Comment: I suspect either the copy provided to you is missing a file, or you have accidentally deleted or moved it. I would get in touch with whomever created the code; As they are expecting a file to be there and it is not.  They might be able to give you more information on where to find it or provide a fresh copy.

Comment: Ok so its the next day and i opened the file.. Now it opens! What the hell. So I didnt move anything. It magically works now. Why is that? Also, now that its working, the table showing now is different than the one that was shown with the errors yesterday. This is weird.

Answer (score 0):

You moved the script so you need to correct the include path:

```
include "client_header.php";
```

This is expecting the include in the current directory, so if you have moved it to a sub directory you could prefix it with `../` or give it the absolute path.

Comment: I didn't move it. I just copied it on a new folder. So there is a backup of the original one.

Comment: copy or move, makes no difference if you are executing the new one.

Comment: I executed the original one. I didn't change a thing on the original.. even in the new one.

Comment: @user1551672 that seems very suspicious to me, it worked fine, then you copied some files, and now doesn't work. I think you moved something...

Comment: Maybe moved files by accident?? I don't know. It's weird cause the table showing in the page is different than what I saw earlier. Its like some ghost changed the codes or something. What the hell.